# Accessing XML file from localhost in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I am reading XML file using javascript then display it in my html page

it is working perfectly on FireFox.

I googled and found that it is because my file is local in my harddisk that is why Chrome and IE do not work, and Chrome gives this error

```
clocks.html:20 Failed to load file:///B:/Data/clocks.xml: 
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: 
http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

so I created a local website and added the file there

```
http://localhost/clocks.xml
```

I can access the file through that link, but when I replace `clocks.xml` in my script with `http://localhost/clocks.xml` ended with page is not working not even in FireFox and getting this error from FireFox

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows 
reading the remote resource at http://localhost/clocks.xml. 
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).[Learn More]
```

how can I get this working in all browsers

my script here

```
        window.onload = function() {
            getClockInformation();
        }

        function getClockInformation() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    updateClocks(this);
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/clocks.xml", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
```

Comment: How are you loading the html file, straight from disk? ie your browser ends up at `file:///some/path/to/file.html`? You would need to load the html file from the same domain, `http://localhost` in your case. Or setup your server to  send out the appropriate cors headers for your xml file

Comment: the file clocks.xml is in the same folder as html page is..

Comment: Yes but are you loading the html page from the localhost url,  ie `http://localhost/file.html`

Comment: no, i just double click on the html it opens like this B:\data\clocks.html

Comment: Yea that causes it to check for CORS since a `file:///` url is considered a dfifferent domain than `http://localhost`. Load it from the localhost like you are the xml file, ie `http://localhost/file.html` and the request will work

Comment: is there anyway it can work directly from the folder, as this is going to be sent to other customers. it is already working on FireFox, the problem is in Chrome

Comment: `since a file:/// url is considered a dfifferent domain` - in Chrome ... Firefox does not have this limitation since, as the OP already points out, `already working in Firefox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just run it directly from disk you won't be able to use ajax as Chrome and probably other browsers just wont allow loading of `file:///` urls.

You can get around this by using a file input or drag and drop operation to get the file

Html

```
Select the clocks.xml file
<input type="file" id="xmlfile">
```

Javascript

```
var fileInput = document.querySelector("#xmlfile");
fileInput.addEventListener("change",function(e){
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function(){
    var data = reader.result;
    //data will now contain the xml text
    //use DOMParser to parse it
    var xmlDocument = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data,"application/xml");
    //then use the various element methods to get the elements you need
    //for instance if you had a <clock> element
    var clockData = xmlDocument.querySelector("clock").textContent
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
})
```

Otherwise you would need to setup cors or load both the html and xml from your server.

[DOMParser api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

[FileReader api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: I added my html to the local domain, works in Chrome but not in IE.