# JS XMLHttpRequest() Connect.open Works for file in folder, but not when http

Tags: javascript, http

I am trying to load an XML file from a HTTP site (will be in the same network) all works fine loading the file in the same folder (as in code part Connect.open("GET", "REPORT.XML", false); ) I tried both true and false and it still doesn't work. What am I missing? As the code below will show undefined for all variable when trying to load anything else than the REPORT.XML not using a http version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Consommation</title>

<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)">
<style>
    <!--
    /* Font Definitions */
    @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
        panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
    @font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
        panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
    /* Style Definitions */
    p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin-top:0in;
        margin-right:0in;
        margin-bottom:10.0pt;
        margin-left:0in;
        line-height:115%;
        font-size:11.0pt;
        font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
    .MsoChpDefault
    {font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
    .MsoPapDefault
    {margin-bottom:10.0pt;
        line-height:115%;}
    @page WordSection1
    {size:11.0in 8.5in;
        margin:42.55pt 1.0in 35.45pt 1.0in;}
    div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
    -->
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
    // Create a connection to the file.
    var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Define which file to open and
    // send the request.
    //Connect.open("GET", "REPORT.XML", false); // THIS WORKS
    //Connect.open("GET", "http://192.168.40.15/REPORT.XML", false); // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    Connect.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1/REPORT.XML", false); // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    Connect.send(null);
    // Place the response in an XML document.
    var TheDocument = Connect.responseXML;
    // Place the root node in an element.
    var Data = TheDocument.childNodes[0];


    //document.write(Data.getElementsByTagName("Name")[2].textContent + " of value of " + Data.getElementsByTagName("ActiveValue")[2].textContent + " " + Data.getElementsByTagName("ActiveUnit")[2].textContent + "<br>");
    //document.write(Data.getElementsByTagName("Name")[6].textContent + " of value of " + Data.getElementsByTagName("ActiveValue")[6].textContent + " " + Data.getElementsByTagName("ActiveUnit")[6].textContent + "<br>");
    //document.write(Data.getElementsByTagName("Name")[10].textContent + " of value of " + Data.getElementsByTagName("ActiveValue")[10].textContent + " " + Data.getElementsByTagName("ActiveUnit")[10].textContent + "<br>");

    var insta = Data.getElementsByTagName("ActiveValue")[2].textContent;
    var jourcour = Data.getElementsByTagName("ActiveValue")[6].textContent;
    var totalvieille = Data.getElementsByTagName("ActiveValue")[10].textContent;


</script>
</head>
<body>

<span lang=FR style='font-size:18.0pt;line-height:115%;color:red'><script language="JavaScript">document.write(insta);</script></span>
<span lang=FR style='font-size:18.0pt;line-height:115%;color:red'><script language="JavaScript">document.write(jourcour);</script></span>
<span lang=FR style='font-size:18.0pt;line-height:115%;color:red'><script language="JavaScript">document.write(totalvieille);</script></span>

</body>
```

Comment: Is your page loaded at 192.168.40.15 or 127.0.0.1? If it's not, for instance if it is at `http://localhost` it will do a CORS check. Check your console to see if you are getting a headers error

Comment: Console is giving me: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
The file is hosted at 192.168.40.15 (other pc) I installed MAMP  to try first if it was not a firewall issue and tried localhost

Comment: Is there a way to load an external XML (the web page is loaded by double clicking on it and opening in the user PC) and then that file needs to load external data

Comment: On some browsers like firefox you can but not on Chrome, and maybe others. They simply don't allow you to do ajax requests from pages loaded that way. You can load a file, but it has to be on their system already [see my answer here about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52359437/560593)